# How do I get CTRL-LEFTCLICK navigation on Ruby to work in IntelliJ 7?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ when editing Java files <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+LEFTCLICK on an identifier takes me to where that identifier is defined.  For some reason it doesn't work when editing Ruby code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the program doesn't know where to find that identifier... it's more of a program use question than a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the case.  When I hover over the identifier, in 95% of cases IntelliJ is able to work out precisely what the identifier is (local variable, member variable, class etc) and show me the fully qualified class name etc in a tool tip.

Even the holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hovering over the identifier shows the blue underline: it's just that nothing happens when I click on it.  I would expect to be taken to where the identifier is defined.  So either I have a configuration issue or there is a bug in IntelliJ - just don't know whicj.